# Change access level of a user at the organizational level programmatically - Azure DevOps Services

Tags: powershell, azure-devops-rest-api

We are trying to change the access level of users at the organization level say for example from stakeholder to basic in Azure DevOps Services programmatically - via REST API/Powershell/ARM. Could you please direct me to some documentation or any sources which can help us through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this via the Azure DevOps REST API via the User Entitlement Endpoint.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlements/update%20user%20entitlement?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0